# Difficulty & Value of replacing suspension forks w disk brakes (for Touring)

Tags: touring, suspension

I need to replace my front suspension forks with hard forks (no suspension). My bike has disk brakes, a dynamo (that seems to attach to the wheel hub), and mud flaps. Are these sorts of things easily added to any non-suspension fork or do I need to find something specifically designed for these needs? If so, what should I look for?

Comment: You must, of course, get a fork that is designed for disk brakes.  The dynamo and mud flaps shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wheel should attach to the new fork with the current hub.

You just need to match the tube diameter and height.

You need to match the height for a bike designed for shock.  Like look at a Salsa Vaya compared to Fargo.  The Fargo comes with solid but can take a suspension.

You did not post the size of the wheel or fork but this is an example of fixed fork that replaces a suspension. [OrgeFork](http://surlybikes.com/parts/forks/ogre_fork)

You need to match brakes.  Often they will support more than 1 brake type.  That Orge supports disc I think - most 29" most do.

And checked used.  Most people go the other direction (solid to shock).

You also posted a question on mounting a rack. Look for fork with mounts for fender and rack.  Why did you decide to not put a rack on the suspension?

As for if you are on a budget should you go ahead and put a rack on shock?
I would say yes use the shock and put the money into a nicer rack and/or nicer bags. 
A decent set of bags is $100. 
Put your lighter stuff up front. 
A mountain bike with shocks for a road touring is not ideal but that is where you are. 
As for a point of failure I would not worry about that unless you have an indication you shocks are failing. 
If you can find a used solid fork **with rack mount** for $40 and can install it yourself then I would do it.  There is a Salsa Fargo fork on ebay right now that multiple attachment points.  If it fits your bike it would be nice.  I don't know how much of a budget you are on.

Comment: I asked these questions separately so i could try to get a better understanding of the spectrum of options (I really appreciate your thoroughness). **Question**: would you advise sticking w/ the shocks instead of going with a hard fork (what if finances are tight)?

Comment: It is appropriate to ask separate questions.  I will add to my answer.

Comment: @jon: What do you hope to gain by switching from a fork with suspension to one without?  It's hard for us to guess what to recommend without knowing your thoughts on this and intended uses.

Comment: @JohnZwinck If you follow his questions he is on a budget and going to do some road touring.  How he got from asking about a touring bike to I need to racks for my suspension is I am sure a good story.

Comment: @JohnZwinck fair point! I've been told that front suspension is a problem for road touring because it's an additional point of failure, adds weight, and not much additional value as there's little off-road riding happening. That said, here I am with my second hand bike and I'm trying to decide where best to spend my bucks. Is a new fork worth it? Sorry for mucking up this question's intent. I'm new to biking and its hard to know where your wisdom will lead me. :)

Comment: @jon: OK, I think I get it.  I would say definitely do not spend money on a replacement fork for a second-hand bike before you start touring.  As I mentioned in a comment on your other question, I personally met a guy who rode from Spain to Singapore with front suspension with panniers mounted and it was no problem.  I doubt your tour is going to be any longer than that, so you should be all right!  And the main thing is to get out and ride, don't worry too much about little things like "is it bad that my fork has suspension?"  Just set the suspension knobs to "hard" to avoid undue bobbing.

Comment: @JohnZwinck brilliant advise. thanks for sticking with me.

Comment: If you have a suspension fork already and don't know if it will be a problem, go to a hardware store and get a couple of spiral hose clamps large enough to fit around the pistons.  Also cut some pieces from an old inner tube.  If, once you've started, the fork turns out to be a bother, wrap inner tube around the pistons and apply the clamps, pushing them tight against the cylinders.  (Probably this will damage the pistons if ridden for hundreds of miles with the clamps in place, but you indicate that the bike isn't that valuable to begin with.)